# How to use static variable to keep track of the increment?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, static

I am using static variable to keep track of the number of hotels added in firebase. Let's say, in start, the value of static variable is 1, then when data is added in firebase, the number is incremented to 2. But, when again the data is added and this view controller is loaded again, the value of static variable gets back to 1 and the new data posted replace the older data. How can I manage that thing? I know that pretty basic and silly question, but sometimes the brain just don't work. Below is the code.

```
class OwnerAddListing2ViewController: UIViewController {
    static var numberOfHotels:Int = 1


    let DataForCurrency : [String] = ["USD", "Rs"]
    let DataForDays : [String] = ["PerNight", "PerWeek", "PerMonth"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        currencyField.inputView = currencyPicker
        daysField.inputView = daysPicker
    }


    @IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let currency = currencyField.text
        let charges = chargesField.text
        let days = daysField.text
        let phone = phoneField.text
        let email = emailField.text

        //Get reference to firebase Database
            let db = Firestore.firestore()

        //Post data tw database
        db.collection("Property").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)").collection("Hotel").document("\(OwnerAddListing2ViewController.numberOfHotels)").setData(["Currency": currency!, "Charges" : charges!, "Days" : days!, "Phone" : phone!, "EmailAddress" : email!], merge: true) {(error) in
                if error != nil {

                }
                else {
                    print("Data Posted Succesfully")
                    OwnerAddListing2ViewController.numberOfHotels = OwnerAddListing2ViewController.numberOfHotels + 1
                }

            }   
    }
```

Comment: you can check the stack trace or print numberOfHotels in viewdidload to check the value.

Comment: Code seems fine. Please debug your code, while posting data to db then check its succeed or giving some error. 
If the data posting is succeed then check value of numberOfHotels just after when its incremented.

Comment: Okay the problem was in wrong use of static here. It was working fine in one cycle of app and the number was incrementing to 2, but the aim was to retain the number of hotels after app start again, and static variable can only retain value in one cycle. So had to use UserDefaults to save Value. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static Variables only keep the data saved in One application Life cycle. As soon as you restart the application, the static variable will be initialized from the default value. If you want to persist the value of your variables throughout , may be you should consider using `UserDefaults` which can store small amount of information. But be careful not to store any sensitive data like passwords.